# Entity Framework 6 convention order not respected with interface types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to establish some default conventions for interfaces using EF6.1.3 code-first migrations but interface-based conventions seem to be treated differently. [Conventions operate in a last wins manner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164#order). Or at least they normally do.

Here's a very simple contrived sample for a database where all string properties should be limited to 200 characters, except for types that implement an `IName` interface, where the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties should be limited to 50 and 100 characters respectively.

```
public interface IName
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class StringConvention : Convention
{
    public StringConvention()
    {
        Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(200));
    }
}

public class NameConvention : Convention
{
    public NameConvention()
    {
        Types<IName>().Configure(c => c.Property(i => i.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired());
        Types<IName>().Configure(c => c.Property(p => p.LastName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired());
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<StringConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<NameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();
    }
}
```

This generates the following `CreateTable` statement in the migration code:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.People",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            FirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
            LastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
            EmailAddress = c.String(maxLength: 200),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

The `NameConvention` is clearly executed as `FirstName` and `LastName` are marked not-nullable (via `IsRequired()`), but the `maxLength` does not override the `StringConvention` even though `NameConvention` is last.

If the `NameConvention` acts upon `Person` directly instead of the `IName` interface, then all works as expected.

```
public class NameConvention : Convention
{
    public NameConvention()
    {
        Types<Person>().Configure(c => c.Property(i => i.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired());
        Types<Person>().Configure(c => c.Property(p => p.LastName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired());
    }
}
```

Generates the following `CreateTable` statement in the migration code:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.People",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            FirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            LastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
            EmailAddress = c.String(maxLength: 200),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

I want to use conventions to establish defaults via interfaces in a separate class library than the concrete types, with the option for the consuming project to override them using configurations but I can't seem to figure out why the `maxLength` is being ignored in this case.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of not *exactly* answering the question being asked ...

I ran into a similar problem where a MaxLength convention was reverting an IsUnicode() convention due to an EF6x bug (sorry, I do not have the link).

My solution was to configure the Convention using the AddAfter<>() extension method. For your code, it would look like this:

```
...
...
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<StringConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.AddAfter<StringConvention>(new NameConvention());
...
...
```

That said, my convention was not constrained to an interface type so the analogy is not an exact match, but it should be easy to verify.

SC

Comment: I tried `AddAfter` but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference. If it was simply an issue of the order they were added, then the concrete class example in my question wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to implement my default max length convention that allows for my interface-based conventions to override the defaults:

I replaced my `Convention`-based `StringConvention` with an `IConceptualModelConvention<EntityType>` implementation:

```
public class StringDefaultMaxLengthConvention :  IConceptualModelConvention<EntityType>, IConvention
{
    private int DefaultMaxLength { get; set; }

    public StringDefaultMaxLengthConvention()
        : this(200)
    {
    }

    public StringDefaultMaxLengthConvention(int defaultMaxLength)
    {
        DefaultMaxLength = defaultMaxLength;
    }

    public void Apply(EntityType item, DbModel model)
    {
        PrimitiveType stringPrimitiveType = PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(PrimitiveTypeKind.String);

        foreach (var property in item.DeclaredProperties.Where(p => p.IsPrimitiveType && p.PrimitiveType == stringPrimitiveType))
        {
            if (!property.MaxLength.HasValue && !property.IsMaxLength)
            {
                property.MaxLength = DefaultMaxLength;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I made sure to add it before `PropertyMaxLengthConvention` as that convention flags everything as `IsMaxLength`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.AddBefore<PropertyMaxLengthConvention>(new StringDefaultMaxLengthConvention());
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<NameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();
    }
}
```

I'd prefer if I could get the original idea working as I prefer working with the fluent API for configurations and conventions but I can live with this if not.